Explicitly set Level in Multi level Sankey using Plotly
I want to explicitly set the flow that categories appears in using the SAME categories for each level. Using plotly it appears that 'pairs' of values are applied then an algorithm is used to work out where the nodes appear.
For example, in the below table A and B should appear at different levels dependent on what the preceding levels were :

